# Как получить комментарии с Youtube на PHP

Tags: php, json, api

знатоки! У меня есть сайт, с протоколом SSL,

Хочу на этом сайте вывести коментарии со своего канала в YouTube. На сайте https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials я создал API key (помечен зеленой галочкой как активный)

Далее создаю ссылку вида:

[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet,replies&videoId=[id]&key=[key]](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet,replies&videoId=%5Bid%5D&key=%5Bkey%5D)

В [id] вбиваю id целевого видеоролика, а в [key] свой API ключ, как в результат ожидалось увидеть что то без ошибок, например JSON. А получается это:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "SSL is required to perform this operation.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "SSL is required to perform this operation.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "sslRequired"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Пробовал получить ответ через file_get_contents, но в ответ FALSE

Как мне получить некий массив с комментариями и распарсить его на своем сайте?

Comment: Что куда вбиваете - код покажите

Comment: $get = file_get_contents('http://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet,replies&videoId=[id]&key=[key]');

var_dump($get);

Comment: @InDevX видно конечно не айс, но этот вариант я рассматривал. При переходе по голой ссылке тоже выдается ошибка SSL Хотя проблем с ним на сайте нет

Comment: `https://` добавьте в начале  ссылки

Comment: @InDevX Есть сдвиги, при переходе по голой ссылке формата "https://..." выдает JSON ответ с другой ошибкой) Теперь говорить что не валидный API key.. хоть копирую с консоли

Comment: ну так ищите ключ

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127676/discussion-between-4-kilograms-and-indevx).